# JavaScript expand object[method] to object.method for calling object.method()

Tags: javascript

If `method = "post"`, how can I make the `rest[method]` expand to `rest.post(uri, body).then(..`?

```
function proxyUrl() {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        proxyFound = url.some(function (element) {
            if (req.url == element) {
                method = req.method.toLowerCase();
                body = req.body;
                //get host to prozy to
                var host;
                arrayProxies.some(function (hostName) {
                    if (proxyList[hostName] == element) {
                        host = hostName;
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                //Make Call...do proxy
                uri = 'https://'+host;
                console.log(method);
                rest[method](uri, body).then(
                    function(response) {
                        res.send(response);
                    }, function(error) {
                        res.send(error.statusCode, error);
                    });

            }
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: `object.foo()` equals `object["foo"]()`

Comment: What is `rest` and where is it defined? Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can provider more useful context information (and help yourself).

Comment: @FelixKling: I'd have guessed that `rest` is a REST api. Or does a response object have a `post` method that returns a promise?

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, noticed that as well, removed my comments. However `res` could still have a `post` method, since we don't know what it is.`*shrug*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `method = "post"`, then it's just `rest[method](uri, body).then(…` - just as you have it in your code. The [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) works as usual with method calls as well.

Comment: Strange, that is what I thought also but it doesn't seem the method `rest.post()` this way.

Comment: Then `rest` might not be what you think it is. What is the problem? Do you get some errors?

Comment: Ah...it was a issue with reslter. I had to add `if (method == "post") { method = "postJson"; }`